# Cannot suspend apps with the PACKAGE_ACCESS delegation

Tags: android, android-management-api

I try to suspend some apps on a fully managed device (Android 7.1.2) using the `setPackagesSuspended()` method ([link to the reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setPackagesSuspended(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20boolean))). According to the documentation, the first parameter of the method is a `ComponentName`:

> **ComponentName**: The name of the admin component to check, or **null** if the caller is a package access delegate. This value must never be **null**.

Despite the documentation a bit paradoxal, I set the value to **null**, since my app has the special delegation from the Android Device Policy:

```
"applications": [
{
  "packageName": "our.business.app",
  "installType": "REQUIRED_FOR_SETUP",
  "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT",
  "managedConfiguration": {
     xxx
   },
  "delegatedScopes": [
    "ENABLE_SYSTEM_APP",
    "PACKAGE_ACCESS"
  ],
  "accessibleTrackIds": [
    "4699927753xxx"
  ]
}
],
```

Unfortunately, I get an exception when I call the method:

> **NullPointerException**: ComponentName is null

Besides that, I don't know if this is related, but I have some weird logs from the Android Device Policy:

```
2020-01-22 15:38:27.835 7741-11774/? I/clouddpc: [CloudDpsClientImpl] Install app request, packagesToInstall: [our.business.app], packagesToUninstall: []
2020-01-22 15:38:33.217 7741-11774/? I/clouddpc: [PlaySyncUtils] Install error. Package name: [our.business.app]. Reason [TRANSIENT_ERROR]. Delay before retry: [0].
2020-01-22 15:38:33.219 7741-11780/? I/clouddpc: [PlaySyncUtils] Install error. Package name: [our.business.app]. Reason [TRANSIENT_ERROR]. Delay before retry: [0].
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setPackagesSuspended()` has been added in API level 24 (ie Android 7.0), which should work on my device. **BUT** the `DELEGATION_PACKAGE_ACCESS` has been added in API 26 (ie Android 8.0). That's why it doesn't work on my device.

It works well on a device with API level 27.